# Calling delegate not reachable?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

```
using System;

namespace _1._75_Using_a_delegate
{
    public class Program
    {

        public delegate int Calculate(int x, int y);

        public int Add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
        public int Multiply(int x, int y) { return x * y; }

         public void UseDelegate()
        {


            Calculate calc = Add;
            Console.WriteLine(calc(3, 4)); //Displays 7


            calc = Multiply;
            Console.WriteLine(calc(3, 4));//Displays 12

        }

       public static void Main()
         {

            //call and execute UseDelegate()

         }



    }
}
```

This should output the above results of 7 and 12.

The delegate function is not directly callable from main in the current state.

1. Why can't the delegate be seen from main?
2. Is it necessary to create a class?
3. How should the delegate function be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call the method at all, and you can't now since the `Main` method is static and your methods are not.

I would recommend to split your code off to a second class, which is easier to call. (Instead of making all methods static)

```
public class Assignment
{ /* all code except the Main method goes here */ }
```

Then, in your `Main` method, instantiate an instance of the `Assignment` class and call `UseDelegate`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Assignment a = new Assignment();
    a.UseDelegate();

    Console.ReadKey(); // to prevent the console from closing immediate
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call the non-static method from static Method so you have to implement another class like

```
internal class Check
{
    public delegate int Calculate(int x, int y);

    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public int Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

    public void UseDelegate()
    {
        Calculate calc = Add;
        Console.WriteLine(calc(3, 4)); //Displays 7

        calc = Multiply;
        Console.WriteLine(calc(3, 4));//Displays 12
    }
}
```

your call it from your Main Method like

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Check().UseDelegate();
        }
```